# Can't connect to computer through Powerline WiFi extender from computer connected directly to router

Tags: powerline-networking

I'm currently using a TP-Link AV600 Powerline WiFi extender to allow devices in my home office (far away from the router) to connect to the Internet wirelessly (which is working fine).

The problem I am having is that if I am on a computer which connects to the router's WiFi, I can't connect (ping, RDP, etc.) to computers which connect to the Powerline's WiFi.

The devices are all on the same subnet: 
Router (PlusNet Hub One): 192.168.1.254 
Powerline (TP-Link AV600): 192.168.1.79 
Computer A (connected to the router's WiFi): 192.168.1.144 
Computer B (connected to the Powerline's WiFi): 192.168.1.148

If I move computer A to the Powerline's WiFi, I can connect fine.

Is this just a limitation of Powerline WiFi extenders in general, this particular model, or is it likely to be a configuration issue in my network?

Comment: Are you only using a single "extender" that acts as a signal repeater? Or do you have a pair of powerline devices (router-ethernet-powerline-powerline-wifi)?

Comment: I have a pair of powerline adapters, so as you describe, computer B connects to the Internet as router-ethernet-powerline-powerline-wifi-computer B, and computer A connects through router-wifi-computer A.

Comment: Does adapter B have an Ethernet port, and have you tried connecting either computer A or computer B to that adapter's Ethernet?

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long to reply, finally had time to test this today.I've tried connecting one computer to the powerline and another to the router and found that if both connect through ethernet, both can ping each other, all good. However, if either or both computers connect through wifi, the computer connecting through the router can ping the other computer, but there's no response the other way, regardless of which is on wifi.

Comment: Are you sure that the powerline connection is established and that the data rate is good?